# Fusion categories with $\mathrm{PSU}(2)_k$ fusion rules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, fusion-categories

Let $R_k$ be a fusion ring with $\mathrm{SU}(2)_k$ fusion rules (or equivalently $A_{k+1}$ fusion rules).
All fusion categories with such fusion rules have been classified by Frohlich and Kerler in their book "Quantum Groups, Quantum Categories and Quantum Field Theory".

$R_k$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ graded ring and by restricting ourselves to the even elements one gets a fusion ring which is often denoted in physics literature by $\mathrm{PSU}(2)_k$.

Is there anything known about the classification of fusion categories with $\mathrm{PSU}(2)_k$ fusion rules? In particular:

- can all of these categories be obtained from the ones with $\mathrm{SU}(2)_k$ fusion rules by restricting the $F$-symbols (or associator) to even elements?
- Let $\#$ denote the number of inequivalent fusion categories (up to both gauge equivalence and automorphisms from the fusion ring). Is $\#\mathrm{PSU}(2)_k = \frac{\#\mathrm{SU}(2)_k}{2}$?

Comment: Appendix to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04409.pdf seems to be relevant.